# Uniformly convergent sequence $(g_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with each $g_n$ having local min at $0$. Does $g$ have local min at $0$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence, maxima-minima

Say I have a sequence of real-valued functions on $\mathbb{R}$ $(g_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $, g_n \xrightarrow[]{\text{uniform}} g$. Say each $g_n$ has a local minimum at $x = 0.$ Will $g$ have a local minimum at $x = 0$ too?

I suspect the answer is no (because not continuity requirements are imposed), but I can't construct a good counterexample. Help?

Comment: $g_n(x)=|x|$, $x\in[-1/n,1/n]$; $g_n(x)=x$, otherwise.

Comment: Or  $g_n(x) = -x^2 - |x|-1/n$ if $|x|<1/n$ and $g_n(x)=-x^2$ otherwise.  Here the functions are continuous, and the limit of the local minima at $x=0$ is a global maximum of the limit function.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need complicated piecewise definitions, and you can have continuous (even smooth) functions: $$g_n(x)=-x^4+\frac1n\frac{x^2}{x^2+1}$$ has a local minimum at $0,$ while $g(x)=-x^4$ has a global maximum, there.